# Find the area of the bounding box of a robot's moves on a grid

Tags: c, comparative-review, coordinate-system

> Given a string of directions (example: `"LLRUDDULRDRU"`) find the area of the rectangle defined by the lowest-left point `(minx, miny)` and the highest-right point `(maxx, maxy)` the robot was in.

The canonical solution I think would be.

```
int area(char* directions) {
    char * c = directions;
    int x=0, y=0, minx=0, maxx=0, miny=0, maxy=0;
    while (*c) {
        if (*c == 'U') {
            y++;
        } else if (*c == 'D') {
            y--;
        } else if (*c == 'R') {
            x++;
        } else if (*c == 'L') {
            x--;
        }

        if (y < miny)
            miny = y;
        if (x < minx)
            minx = x;
        if (y > maxy)
            maxy = y;
        if (x > maxx)
            maxx = x;

        c++;
    }
    return (maxx - minx) * (maxy - miny);
}
```

The problem I see with this is that the indentation is switched often making it hard to read. That's why I tend to exploit the fact C's logical operators return numbers `1` or `0`.

```
int area(char * directions) {
    char * c = direction;
    int x=0, y=0, minx=0, maxx=0, miny=0, maxy=0;
    while (*c) {
        y += (*c == 'U') - (*c == 'D');
        x += (*c == 'R') - (*c == 'L');

        minx = (x < minx) ? x : minx;
        miny = (y < miny) ? y : miny;
        maxx = (x > maxx) ? x : maxx;
        maxy = (y > maxy) ? y : maxy;

        c++;
    }

     return (maxx - minx) * (maxy - miny);
}
```

However doing this feels '*too hacky*'.

Is doing this a good practice at all?

Comment: Welcome to CR! Please see [ask] for guidelines about what question titles should look like on this site. In short: tell us what your code is doing.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you [edit] the question to only include the code you're actually using - the way you're presenting it sounds like you're more interested in an opiniated yes/no answer than feedback about any & all aspects of your code - see our [help/on-topic] for all the details.

Answer (score 6):

## Function signature

It appears you're only reading from `directions`, so pass that as a pointer to const.

## `while` loop

You initialize `c` before the `while` loop and increment it at the end of each iteration.  Writing it as `for` will convey the intent more clearly.

## Chained conditions

Your first `if`/`else if` chain is always testing the same variable, so a `switch` statement seems more appropriate:

```
    switch (*c) {
    case 'U': ++y; break;
    case 'D': --y; break;
    case 'R': ++x; break;
    case 'L': --x; break;
    }
```

You might want to add a `default` case to indicate when malformed input is received.  I can't tell from the context whether it would be appropriate to print something to `stderr` or to return an error code (perhaps as a negative return value), so I'll leave that to you.

## Don't test all bounds each time

We can now observe that we only need to check `y` against `maxy` if we've incremented `y`, so we can move that test into the switch; similarly with the other cases:

```
int area(char const *directions)
{
    int x=0, y=0,
        minx=0, maxx=0,
        miny=0, maxy=0;
    for (char const *c = directions;  *c;  ++c) {
        switch (*c) {
        case 'U':
            ++y;
            if (y > maxy) maxy = y;
            break;
        case 'D':
            --y;
            if (y < miny) miny = y;
            break;
        case 'R':
            ++x;
            if (x > maxx) maxx = x;
            break;
        case 'L':
            --x;
            if (x < minx) minx = x;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (maxx - minx) * (maxy - miny);
}
```

You might want to consider using a `max()` function to re-write `++x; if (x > maxx) maxx = x;` as `maxx = max(maxx, ++x);`, but I can't really say that one is better than the other - too close to call.  Similarly, you might decide that returning an unsigned type is more appropriate, but that really depends on the code you're calling it from.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion is what I was thinking, too.  Note, however, that if we interpret the "bounding box of a robot's moves on a grid" as the smallest box containing all squares of the grid ever occupied by the robot, then this (and the OP's) solution is off by one in each dimension.  The robot occupies one grid square even if it never moves, and one *additional* grid square in each dimension for the net extent of its movements in that dimension.

Comment: Expression like `maxx = max(maxx, ++x);` may lead to error if `max` is a `#define`d macro! Use it only if you're sure `max()` is a function. IMHO moving incrementation into the condition will suffice: `if (++x > maxx) maxx = x;`

Answer (score 4):

There really isn't a particular need to store minimum values, nor is there any reason to use a separate variable for the character pointer.  Here's another way to do it that avoids both the long `if`/`else` chain and the four comparisons for each direction (only one is needed):

```
int area (const char *directions) {
    unsigned x = 0;
    unsigned y = 0;
    unsigned maxx = 0;
    unsigned maxy = 0;
    for ( ; *directions; ++directions) {
        switch (*directions) {
            case 'U':
                if (++y > maxy) {
                    ++maxy;
                }
                break;
            case 'D':
                if (y == 0) {
                    ++maxy;
                } else {
                    --y;
                }
                break;
            case 'R':
                if (++x > maxx) {
                    ++maxx;
                }
                break;
            case 'L':
                if (x == 0) {
                    ++maxx;
                } else {
                    --x;
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("Ignoring unknown direction '%c'\n", *directions);
        }
    }
    return maxx*maxy;
}
```

Comment: If you go with this approach, then I recommend renaming `maxx` and `maxy` to `bbox_width` and `bbox_height`, respectively.

Comment: One could certainly rename the variables as you suggest, but whether you think of it as `bbox_width` or `maxx` depends on whether you think of the movement as expanding a bounding box or re-normalizing the origin.  I could argue it either way, but ultimately I agree that  each variable should have a good name that indicates what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

This is way to hacky:

```
    y += (*c == 'U') - (*c == 'D');
    x += (*c == 'R') - (*c == 'L');
```

Relying on bool to int conversion makes the code hard to read.

This is fine (and easy to read):

```
    minx = (x < minx) ? x : minx;
    miny = (y < miny) ? y : miny;
    maxx = (x > maxx) ? x : maxx;
    maxy = (y > maxy) ? y : maxy;
```

Though I would use the functions to provide more context. In C++ I would have used:

```
    minx = std::min(x, minx);
    miny = std::min(y, miny);
    maxx = std::max(x, maxx);
    maxy = std::max(y, maxy);
```

Or provide the appropriate functions.